# Rendering controller within a page

Tags: symfony, twig, render

I am trying to render a controller within my template, for the controller to render I have:

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $review = new Review();

    $form = $this->createForm(ReviewType::class, $review,[
        'action' => $request->getUri()
    ]);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isValid()) {

        $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $manager->persist($review);
        $manager->flush();

    }

    return $this->render('BookReviewsBundle:Review:index.html.twig',
        ['form' => $form->createView()]);
}
```

Within the index.html.twig template the controller returns I have:

```
{% block body %}
  {{ form_start(form) }}
  {{ form_end(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

And then the page I want to render the controller on:

```
{{ render(controller("BookReviewsBundle:Review:create")) }}
```

However, I get this error:

**An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Proxies__CG__\Book\BookBundle\Entity\Book could not be converted to string")**

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is there potentially a spelling mistake somehwere? I see in the error message: `\Reviewr\BookBundle\Entity\Book` Notice the spelling of `Reviewr`.

Comment: @AlvinBunk Sorry, I've updated question

Comment: You mean you have: `{{ render(controller("BookReviewsBundle:Review:create")) }}` in your Twig file? That doesn't seem right. Does your `createAction` have a route? Use the command line `php bin/console debug:router` to show your routes.

Comment: @AlvinBunk The route is create_review and the path is /bookreview

Comment: Can you comment out the `render(controller...` part in your Twig file, and then browse to `http://localhost/bookreview` and see if your form shows properly with no errors. Replace localhost with your hostname etc...

Comment: @AlvinBunk i tried that and it gives "Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Reviewr\BookBundle\Entity\Book could not be converted to string"

Comment: I think you are looking in the wrong spot.  Your code is about the review object but the error is about the Book entity.  Somewhere I suspect you are trying to render a book object like {{ book }} or maybe {{ review.book }}

Comment: Please show us full code of twig file

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this:

```
$form = $this->createForm(ReviewType::class, $review);
```

I don't think you can pass the 3rd parameter. Can you try this please - don't know if it will work though.

Comment: Have you also cleared the cache with: `php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod`

Comment: Not certain how to help now. You could try the debug url; by appending `app_dev.php` to the URL. For example `http://localhost/app_dev.php/bookreview` You might be able to see more helpful information...